# How to make OkHttp request faster?

Tags: android, post, android-asynctask, okhttp

I make a **POST** request to secure server and it takes quite a long time. I want to make it faster. Is there some chance to do it? It looks like this:

```
  private class GetTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Call mCallToServer;
    private String mAccessToken;
    private OkHttpClient mHttpClient;
    private JSONObject mResponseJSON;
    private Response mResponseFromServer;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
      mHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

      mCallToServer = mHttpClient.newCall(requestToOAuth());
      try {
        mResponseFromServer = mCallToServer.execute();
        mResponseJSON = new JSONObject(mResponseFromServer.body().string());
        mAccessToken = mResponseJSON.getString(getString(R.string.access_token_key));

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, mAccessToken);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, JWTUtils.decoded(mAccessToken));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return mAccessToken;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
      super.onPostExecute(token);
    }
  }
```

Maybe another library or something like that?

Comment: You can't really control this sort of things because it can have a lot of root causes: your network is slow, the server has a lot of request to process in the same time or the request really takes some time to complete. Best chance is to try it from Postman (or something similar) to see if the time needed to receive the response is the same. If true, you can't really have what to do, but if not you should see what else you do while sending the request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, try the experimental EventListener API of OkHttp 3.9.0 to see where it is spending time.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Events

It also depends how important the speed is.  How much you want to trade correctness for speed.  But there are tons of reasons that could break so you would need fallback to the correct solution.

- If its DNS and you have known hosts you could use those for the first request.
- Run warm up requests ASAP to establish the first connection ASAP.
- Ensure HTTP/2 is working.
- If the response is big, stream the contents to start processing on first byte instead of last.